# Read list of nested jsons in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a json file that I read with the following code.

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

with open('file.json') as json_data:
    d = json.load(json_data)
    json_data.close()
    pprint(d)
```

This gives the following list (not dict):

```
[{'heading': 120.078125,
  'latitude': 60.84809244149443,
  'longitude': 12.706842578952859,
  'warning': None},
 {'heading': 178.2421875,
  'latitude': 60.847404287244046,
  'longitude': 12.70678398944969,
  'warning': {'disabled': True,
              'latitude': 60.8464254391783,
              'longitude': 12.70724018571071,
              'signal': [{'latitude': 52.388542281214,
                         'longitude': 4.6362899175721},
                        {'latitude': 52.388602884476,
                         'longitude': 4.6350475833697}]

             }}]
```

The problem I find is with the nested Json "warning"
When I use the following code to flatten the JSON

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize    
df = json_normalize(d)
```

I get a dataframe with a JSON in the column signal.
When I use the following code (instead of the previous) for flattening the JSON

```
df = json_normalize(d,"warning")
```

I get the following error

```
string indices must be integers
```

Can anyone help me to get a dataframe without JSONs?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't need `json_data.close()` inside your `with` statement. Context manager is handling that for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your new `json` is basically a list of dictionaries where some dictionaries may contain another dictionary containing a list of dictionaries. Since there is no structure to this, [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html) is not the way to go (note that `json_normalize` is for semi-structured `json` according to the docs and doesn't for instance allow for one record to exist in one dict but not in another).

You will therefor have to do some manual reshaping of your `json` before you read it into `pandas`. One idea could be to flatten the entire thing:

```
def flatten_json(y):
    #  As seen here: https://towardsdatascience.com/flattening-json-objects-in-python-f5343c794b10
    out = {}

    def flatten(x, name=''):
        if type(x) is dict:
            for a in x:
                flatten(x[a], name + a + '_')
        elif type(x) is list:
            i = 0
            for a in x:
                flatten(a, name + str(i) + '_')
                i += 1
        else:
            out[name[:-1]] = x

    flatten(y)
    return out

df = json_normalize([flatten_json(row) for row in d])
print(df)

      heading   latitude  longitude warning_disabled  warning_latitude  \
0  120.078125  60.848092  12.706843              NaN               NaN   
1  178.242188  60.847404  12.706784             True         60.846425   

   warning_longitude  warning_signal_0_latitude  warning_signal_0_longitude  \
0                NaN                        NaN                         NaN   
1           12.70724                  52.388542                     4.63629   

   warning_signal_1_latitude  warning_signal_1_longitude  
0                        NaN                         NaN  
1                  52.388603                    4.635048
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I edited the original problem. The problem is with signal, there is a list of jsons in the dataframe. Apologies for the confusion